# How to show cursor automatically in search bar in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cursor, uisearchbar

I have search bar in viewcontroller. here when i tap on searchbar then cursor is showing,  but i need when i reach the viewcontroller i need to show cursor on search bar. how to do taht

**code:** I have tried below code.. with this code when i tap on search bar cursor showing.. i need when i reach this viewcontroller cursor automatically display on search bar.. how? please do guide

```
class PlaceViewController: UIViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

var resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController?
var searchController: UISearchController?
var delegate: PlaceViewControllerDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
    title = "Select Address".localizedWithLanguage

    
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
    searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController
    searchController?.searchBar.placeholder = "please start typing here"
    searchController?.searchBar.tintColor = view.tintColor
    searchController?.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    searchController?.delegate = self
    searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController?.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()

    let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: 45.0))
    subView.addSubview((searchController?.searchBar)!)
    view.addSubview(subView)
    definesPresentationContext = true
}

private func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    searchController?.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    return true
}



func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.endEditing(true)
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
}
```

Comment: I think you need to call `becomeFirstResponder()` in `viewDidAppear()` rather than `viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score 1):

Please add the `becomeFirstResponder` line of code inside a `DispatchQueue` async function like this. It should work.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.searchController?.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

You need to make searchBar become first responder on the main thread using the `DispatchQueue` async method.

Comment: thanks, if i write `self.searchController?.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()` in didappear then its worked

Comment: Using only `self` will not work either adding it inside an `async` method or calling it with the `viewDidAppear()` method seems to make it work.

Comment: `viewDidAppear()` is the appropriate time to do something like setting an initial `firstResponder`.  Cocoa/CocoTouch always calls UI related methods on the main thread as part of the main run loop.  As long as you do your UI updates in those methods, you're doing it the right place.   You have to worry about specifying for it to run on the main thread when, for example, you call UI methods in a completion handler, where you don't know what queue it might execute on (or you *do* know and it's not the main queue).

Comment: @ChipJarred Agreed. 
I suggested the async method as the question had all the code written in `viewDidLoad()`. I assumed @swiftIOS wanted this to happen only when the view loaded and not every time it appeared.

Comment: I say "you're doing it in the right place" I mean with respect to which `DispatchQueue`.  It might not be the right place with respect to the `View` life-cycle, such as becoming `firstResponder` in `viewDidLoad()` which is too early (and might not even be called if your view/controller is every programmatically created rather than loaded from a Storyboard).

Comment: @CedanMisquith, that's a good point, though I think for a search bar, you probably do want it to become first responder every time it is shown.  That's not necessarily the case for other views... you might for example want view that has multiple fields to remember which one was first responder when it was last closed, and rather than always going to the same one.